# PHP preg_match matching text between multiple occurrance of same tags

Tags: php, preg-match

How to match text

```
$line = "study of 557 adults suffering from sleep";
```

from

```
 $content = "The International Journal of Nursing published a
<b>study of 557 adults suffering</b>
<br>
<b>from sleep</b>
disorders. In this study, music was played when they ...";
```

and somtimes the content can be

```
 $content = "The International Journal of Nursing published a
<b>study of 557 adults suffering from sleep</b>
disorders. In this study, music was played when they ...";
```

so i need one solution that can be applicable on both

```
preg_match("#<b>$line</b>#is",$content,$match);
```

Comment: So you want all in between bold tag?

Comment: Take a look at the related questions

Comment: I want to match $line in both $content with single solution

Comment: @alreadycoded.com Is none of the answers good enough? What have we missed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this? https://regex101.com/r/PDehGB/2

```
$pattern = '/<b>study.*?of.*?557.*?adults.*?suffering.*?from.*?sleep<\/b>/ms';
```

With this pattern it will take care of any new lines and still keep the $line.

You can explode the $line on " " and build the pattern with `implode(".*?", $arr)`

Comment: @AlivetoDie Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex (https://regex101.com/r/elRsha/2):

```
$line = "study of 557 adults suffering from sleep";

$content = "The International Journal of Nursing published a
<b>study of 557 adults suffering</b>
<br>
<b>from sleep</b>
disorders. In this study, music was played when they ...";

$line = implode('(?:[\n\s\t]*(?:<.+>)*[\n\s\t]*)*', explode(' ', $line));

preg_match("#($line)#is",$content,$match);
print_r($match);
```

Answer (score 0):

First remove HTML tag from string using [strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) function and then remove newlines from string.

```
$line = "study of 557 adults suffering from sleep";

$content = "The International Journal of Nursing published a
<b>study of 557 adults suffering</b>
<br>
<b>from sleep</b>
disorders. In this study, music was played when they ...";

echo preg_match("#$line#is",trim(preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', strip_tags($content))),$match);
```